# Are there any suggestions to getting an ESP8266 Lua client talking to a Redis database?

Tags: redis, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a basic ESP8266 board which I am trying to configure to talk to a Redis database in order to send sensor values.

- I have a working firmware on the board.
- the board connects successfully to WiFi
- I can ping the board from the laptop running the redis-server instance
- I am using the `redis.lua` module from the NodeMCU firmware Git repository.

I am having zero success getting the Redis client on the ESP8266 board to talk to the redis-server instance.

```
 > redis=dofile("redis.lua").connect("172.23.1.2","6379")
 > 
 >  redis:publish("a","b")
 >  redis.lua:20: not connected
 >  stack traceback:
 >  [C]: in function 'send'
 >  redis.lua:20: in function 'publish'
 >  stdin:1: in main chunk
```

I have checked the redis-server and it will connect with the local redis-cli instance happily.

I will do further tests on the network layer in the ESP8266, but in the meantime if anyone has any further suggestions, they would be gratefully received.

Comment: Can your ESP8266 talk to the outside world at all? You could run a few low-level socket connection tests with the net module e.g. https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/net/#netsocketon.

Comment: Yes, it appears that it can. I am able to see a TCP handshake occurring via wireshark on the laptop I am using but nothing further after that. I am also attempting to code the same test using the arduino IDE. Same result - just a SYN/ACK at the TCP layer, no data and the monitor reports that the connection fails.Something in the network layer I think. I can ping the ESP8266 board with response.